# Mvvm Cross Xamarin.iOS - How can I bind an alert action to the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am working on a Xamarin.iOS project with a ViewController that requires an alert to display along with confirm and cancel actions. If the confirm action is clicked
a segue to another view should trigger while clicking cancel closes the alert and allows the user to remain on the current view. Unfortunately I have not been able to find any examples or documentation about how to achieve this with Mvvm cross's ViewModel to ViewModel navigation pattern.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Alerts are a View concern. Seems like a good fit for using MvxInteraction: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/advanced/mvxinteraction

Comment: Thanks - MvxInteraction was the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [ACR User Dialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) library. It has the most common popup solutions included, such as confirmation prompts, alerts, action sheets, e.g.